# python get checkbutton value after end of mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to find out, which checkbuttons were checked after application is closed.
If i save checkbuttons values in any collection, it's not possible to have an access to that collection after application is destroyed.

```
app = Application(path_to_files)
app.initialize(data)
app.mainloop()
#i want to know all checkbuttons values on this line
```

**checkerGUI.py**

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import webbrowser
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import ctypes

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, pwd="", master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.initImages(pwd)
        self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.index = 0
        self.master.bind("<Return>", self.close)
        self.grid()
        self.games = []
        self.gamesHiddenFlags = {}

    def close(self, event):
        self.master.destroy()

    def getGamesHiddenFlags(self):
        return self.gamesHiddenFlags

    def initialize(self, games):
        self.games = games
        for game in self.games:
            self.gamesHiddenFlags[game.name] = tk.BooleanVar()
            self.createWidgetsFromGame(game, self.gamesHiddenFlags[game.name])

    def initImages(self, path):
        self.images = {}
        buf = Image.open(os.path.join(path, "images", "Classic.png"))
        buf = buf.resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # The (250, 250) is (height, width)
        self.images['Classic'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buf)

        buf = Image.open(os.path.join(path, "images", "Jeopardy.png"))
        buf = buf.resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.images['Jeopardy'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buf)

        buf = Image.open(os.path.join(path, "images", "On-site.png"))
        buf = buf.resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.images['On-site'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buf)

        buf = Image.open(os.path.join(path, "images", "On-line.png"))
        buf = buf.resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.images['On-line'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buf)

    def google_link_callback(event, site):
        webbrowser.open_new(site)

    def ShowImages(self, frame_in, type_img, place_img):
        type_img = type_img.replace("Attack-Defense", "Classic").replace("Attack", "Classic")
        type_img = type_img.replace("Hack quest", "Jeopardy")
        label = tk.Label(frame_in, image=self.images[type_img])
        label.pack(side="right")

        label = tk.Label(frame_in, image=self.images[place_img])
        label.pack(side="right")

    def createWidgetsFromGame(self, game, flag):
        frame = tk.Frame(self, relief='sunken')
        frame.grid(row=0, column=self.index, sticky="WN")
        frame_in = tk.Frame(frame)
        frame_in.grid(row=0, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Label(frame_in, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="Игра: ")
        header.pack(expand=True, fill="x", side="left")

        self.ShowImages(frame_in, game.type, game.place_type)

        header = tk.Label(frame, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="Состояние: ")
        header.grid(row=1, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Label(frame, anchor='nw', justify="left", text="Дата проведения: ", height=2)
        header.grid(row=3, sticky="WEN", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Label(frame, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="Продолжительность: ")
        header.grid(row=5, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Label(frame, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="Сайт игры: ")
        header.grid(row=6, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Label(frame, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="Ранг: ")
        header.grid(row=7, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text="Не показывать: ", variable=flag)  # There is variable
        header.grid(row=8, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        self.index += 1

        frame2 = tk.Frame(self, relief='sunken')
        frame2.grid(row=0, column=self.index, sticky="WN")

        header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text=game.name)
        header.grid(row=0, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text=game.state)
        header.grid(row=1, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text=game.date['start'].strftime("с %d %B в %H:%M"))
        header.grid(row=2, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text=game.date['end'].strftime("до %d %B в %H:%M"))
        header.grid(row=3, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="%d дней %d часов" % (game.duration['days'], game.duration['hours']))
        header.grid(row=4, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", fg='blue', font=tkFont.Font(underline=1, size=10), cursor="hand2", text=game.site)
        header.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.google_link_callback(game.site))
        header.grid(row=5, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text=game.rank)
        header.grid(row=6, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

        self.index += 1
```

Comment: There's usually no need to do this, but if you really need to you can have a function called whenever a check button is updated and save the values in a variable.

Comment: If anyone knows better solution, please post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I modified your code a bit. You will find explanations as comments inside the code. 
I added the protocol method (which you can call with `self.master.protocol`) and changed the close method, so that before it destroys the app it iterates through the checkbuttons and collects the flags in a directory, which then is converted to a global list.

To test it I had to comment out the image part of your code and create my own game class to have a list of fake-games.
Don't know whether my solution is elegant, but under my test conditions it worked.

So after `app.mainloop()` try `print(out)`, which will give you a list of zeroes and ones.

Hope it helps.
Ah, and please check the indention! This editor here did something strange to it, when I pasted my code.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import webbrowser
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import ctypes
```

class Application(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, pwd="", master=None):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.initImages(pwd)
    self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    self.index = 0
    self.master.bind("<Return>", self.close_by_keyboard)#changed 
    self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close_by_mouse)#added
    self.grid()
    self.games = []
    self.gamesHiddenFlags = {}
    self.flags = {} #collection of flags
    global out #variable will exist after Application object is destroyed  
    out = [] #List of flags for later use

#get the variable and exit in case you are closing with a mouse click:
def close_by_mouse(self):
    self.get_variables()
    self.master.destroy()

#same as above for closing with return key:
def close_by_keyboard(self, event):
    self.get_variables()
    self.master.destroy()

def get_variables(self):
    for i in self.flags: 
        out.append(self.flags[i].get())


def getGamesHiddenFlags(self):
    return self.gamesHiddenFlags

def initialize(self, games):
    self.games = games
    for game in self.games:
        self.gamesHiddenFlags[game.name] = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.createWidgetsFromGame(game, self.gamesHiddenFlags[game.name])

def initImages(self, path):
    self.images = {}
    buf = Image.open(os.path.join(path, "images", "Classic.png"))
    buf = buf.resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # The (250, 250) is (height, width)
    self.images['Classic'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buf)

    buf = Image.open(os.path.join(path, "images", "Jeopardy.png"))
    buf = buf.resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.images['Jeopardy'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buf)

    buf = Image.open(os.path.join(path, "images", "On-site.png"))
    buf = buf.resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.images['On-site'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buf)

    buf = Image.open(os.path.join(path, "images", "On-line.png"))
    buf = buf.resize((20, 20), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.images['On-line'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buf)

def google_link_callback(event, site):
    webbrowser.open_new(site)

def ShowImages(self, frame_in, type_img, place_img):
    type_img = type_img.replace("Attack-Defense", "Classic").replace("Attack", "Classic")
    type_img = type_img.replace("Hack quest", "Jeopardy")
    label = tk.Label(frame_in, image=self.images[type_img])
    label.pack(side="right")

    label = tk.Label(frame_in, image=self.images[place_img])
    label.pack(side="right")

def createWidgetsFromGame(self, game, flag):
    frame = tk.Frame(self, relief='sunken')
    frame.grid(row=0, column=self.index, sticky="WN")
    frame_in = tk.Frame(frame)
    frame_in.grid(row=0, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    header = tk.Label(frame_in, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="Игра: ")
    header.pack(expand=True, fill="x", side="left")

    self.ShowImages(frame_in, game.type, game.place_type)

    header = tk.Label(frame, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="Состояние: ")
    header.grid(row=1, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    header = tk.Label(frame, anchor='nw', justify="left", text="Дата проведения: ", height=2)
    header.grid(row=3, sticky="WEN", column=self.index)

    header = tk.Label(frame, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="Продолжительность: ")
    header.grid(row=5, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    header = tk.Label(frame, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="Сайт игры: ")
    header.grid(row=6, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    header = tk.Label(frame, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="Ранг: ")
    header.grid(row=7, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    self.flags[self.index]=tk.IntVar()        
    header = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text="Не показывать: ", variable=self.flags[self.index])  # There is variable
    header.grid(row=8, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    self.index += 1

    frame2 = tk.Frame(self, relief='sunken')
    frame2.grid(row=0, column=self.index, sticky="WN")

    header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text=game.name)
    header.grid(row=0, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text=game.state)
    header.grid(row=1, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text=game.date['start'].strftime("с %d %B в %H:%M"))
    header.grid(row=2, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text=game.date['end'].strftime("до %d %B в %H:%M"))
    header.grid(row=3, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text="%d дней %d часов" % (game.duration['days'], game.duration['hours']))
    header.grid(row=4, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", fg='blue', font=tkFont.Font(underline=1, size=10), cursor="hand2", text=game.site)
    header.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.google_link_callback(game.site))
    header.grid(row=5, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    header = tk.Label(frame2, anchor="nw", justify="left", text=game.rank)
    header.grid(row=6, sticky="WE", column=self.index)

    self.index += 1</pre></code>

Comment: I use `Application()` not `Tk()`, so python says there is no `protocol()` method. And i use my form as the messagebox, but with different content. So i need have return value every time it destroys.

Comment: Could you just post more of your code? Which modules did you import? I thought "Application()" was a class written by yourself?!

Comment: I will check that later today.

Comment: So, can i somehow get checkboxes values after mainloop finished?